# Coinbase Commerce API response error : required pricing_type

Tags: json, postman, coinbase-api

I was using postman and gave the parameter of the of the pricing_type
as 'fixed_price' The example:

```
{"local_price":{"amount":10,"currency":"USD"},"metadata":{"customer_id":"1","customer_name":"Rafid"},"name":"10USD","description":"primary","pricing_type": "fixed_price","redirect_url":"x"}
```

The output is showing an error that:

> error:{    message: "Required parameter missing: pricing_type"
> type: "invalid_request" }

why in spite of giving the type it is showing the parameters are missing?